# Getting list of facebook page's comments?

Tags: facebook

We are in need of a small application that interacts with facebook. Whether integrated as a facebook application, or hitting external APIs, it needs to do the following:

1. have access to a specific page
2. whenever new comments appear, specific people are notified (as long
   as I can get a page's comments I can work the rest out)
3. whenever someone comments, an email is sent to them (again, if I can
   get page's comments, and contact info of whoever commented, I can do
   this)

I'm researching this, but if anybody knows already if this is possible, and if so could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with FQL